# try/catch not working in Java?

Tags: java, android, qt, exception

I am making an app for android in Qt. So in order to use the Google API I need to implement Java. So I have looked through the QtNotifier example and I am trying to implement the same as a starter.

This Java example comes from the QtNotifier example aswell so it should work the same but it doesn't. I have tried to debug it using the Qt debugger but the breakpoints do not seem to trigger So I added println statements to see at which line it goes wrong. But this is not enough so I am trying to print a stacktrace using a catch/try clause.

I have implemented it like this:

```
package org.qtproject.qt5.example;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class NotificationClient extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity
{
    private static NotificationManager m_notificationManager;
    private static Notification.Builder m_builder;
    private static NotificationClient m_instance;

    public NotificationClient()
    {
        System.out.println("it works2222");
        m_instance = this;
    }

    public static void notify(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);

        try {
            if (m_notificationManager == null) {
                System.out.println("1111");
                m_notificationManager = (NotificationManager)m_instance.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                System.out.println("2222");
                m_builder = new Notification.Builder(m_instance);
                System.out.println("3333");
                m_builder.setContentTitle("A message from Qt!");
                System.out.println("4444");
            }

            System.out.println("5555");
            m_builder.setContentText(s);
            System.out.println("6666");
            m_notificationManager.notify(1, m_builder.build());
            System.out.println("7777");

        } catch(Exception e) {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            String errorDetail = writer.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
I/System.out( 4768): test string
I/System.out( 4768): 1111
```

It would seem that m_instance is still null because "System.out.println("it works2222");" does not get called. But the error does not get caught.

Is it because this is an error that is not an exception?

I have also tried running the QtNotifier app but the printstatement inside.

```
public NotificationClient()
{
    System.out.println("it works2222");
    m_instance = this;
}
```

But that is also not called in the QtNotifier app.

**My question is: How can I trace this error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, there are both `Errors` and `Exceptions`. Normally, an `Error` is significant enough that your program should just crash and exit. However, for debugging purposes, if you want to catch both you should

```
catch (Throwable t)
{
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

to get information on both.